# Complexity of an optimization problem with larger feasible set of an NP-hard problem

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity, integer-programming

Suppose the following problem is NP-hard:

\begin{eqnarray} 
   \min & f(\boldsymbol{x})\\
    s.t. & \\
   A\boldsymbol{x} &= b\\
\boldsymbol{x} & \in Z^n
\end{eqnarray}

Then what can we say about the complexity of the following problem:

\begin{eqnarray} 
   \min & f(\boldsymbol{x})\\
    s.t. & \\
   B\boldsymbol{x} &= d\\
\boldsymbol{x} & \in Z^n
\end{eqnarray} 
where $ \{ \boldsymbol{x} : A\boldsymbol{x} = b\} \subseteq  \{ \boldsymbol{x} : B\boldsymbol{x} = d\}$ ?

Comment: When we say a problem is NP-hard, we do not have in mind that a particular instance of that problem is NP-hard, but rather that *as a class* of instances, the ability to compute the solution (for an arbitrary instance of the class) can be harnessed (through polynomial-time conversions of data) to compute the solution to instances of *any other* class of NP (computational) problems.  So your Question does not make much sense when you ask about the complexity of two (related) instances of this integer programming problem.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, not much.  Some extreme cases are

1. $B = A$ and $d=b$, in which case the complexities are the same too, and
2. $B=0$ and $d=0$, in which case the second problem is trivial.

The problems (more precisely, their decision versions) are in $NP$, because given $x$ you can verify the value of $f(x)$ and the constraint $Bx=d$ in polynomial time.